# What's the difference between these two theorems?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

On p. 124 of Gamut's [*Logic, Language and Meaning*, v. 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=5gOujgEACAAJ), there's the following theorem:

> **Theorem 5**
> If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent, $\phi$ is a subformula of $\chi$, and $[\psi/\phi]\chi$ is the formula obtaind by replacing this subformula $\phi$ in $\chi$ by $\psi$, then $\chi$ and $[\psi/\phi]\chi$ are equivalent.

Then, after the proof-sketch of this theorem, there's the following (my emphasis):

> The same reasoning also proves the following, ***stronger*** theorem (in which $\phi$, $\psi$, $\chi$, $[\psi/\phi]\chi$ are the same as above):
>
> **Theorem 6** *(Principle of extensionality for sentences in predicate logic)*
> $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi \vDash \chi \leftrightarrow [\psi/\phi]\chi$.

I have a hard time telling these two apart, let alone discerning that **6** is stronger than **5**.

I read the expression to the left of the $\vDash$ in **6** as "$\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent", which is exactly the premise of **5**.  Likewise, I read the expression to the right of the $\vDash$ in **6** as "$\chi$ and $[\psi/\phi]\chi$ are equivalent", exactly the conclusion on **5**.

The only possible difference I can *guess* is that maybe the equivalence in **5** is "logical equivalence", and the one in **6** is "material equivalence".  If so, I still don't understand why **6** is stronger.  Even if its premise is weaker, so is its conclusion.

---

**UPDATE**

OK, here's one possible elucidation.  Let's suppose that, in **5**, "equivalent" means "logically equivalent".  This means that, *for all models*, $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is true.  So **5** could be interpreted as a corollary of **6**.  In words,

> If $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is true for all models, then $\chi \leftrightarrow [\psi/\phi]\chi$ is true for all models.

The reason why **6** is stronger than **5** is that **5** is a statement about the case where $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is true *for all models*, whereas **6** does not have this requirement.  In fact, **6** that for all the models for which $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is true (however many these may be), $\chi \leftrightarrow [\psi/\phi]\chi$ is also true.

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: We have "equivalent" vs. $\leftrightarrow$ in two places and "If ... then" vs. $\vDash$ in one place. In order to correctly guess the meaning of the natural language phrases, one would need to study the proof of theorem 5, I suppose ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have the correct interpretation.

The $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ in 6 is a logic statement that contains a material conditional ... which we typically read as "$\phi$ if and only if $\psi$" ...  but that is *not* the same as saying that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent. And when logicians talk about 'equivalence', they  mean 'logical equivalence', so that's the same thing. So no, don't interpret a biconditional as a statement about (logical) equivalence!

Example:

$\phi$ is (logically) equivalent to $\neg \neg \phi$ ... but *that* we typically write as $\phi \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg \phi$ .  Note the $\Leftrightarrow$ is the (meta!)-logical symbol we use to talk about equivalence .. again, this is not the same as $\leftrightarrow$

On the other hand, in logic we may encounter something like $p \leftrightarrow q$ ... but clearly $p$ and $q$ are not logically equivalent.

5 talks about the substitution of logically equivalent statements, i.e. where $\phi \Leftrightarrow \psi$.

But 6 talks about a substitution principle involving a biconditional $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$.

5 is a special case of 6 (and thus 6 is stronger), since if $\phi \Leftrightarrow \psi$, then obviously it will be true that $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$, but not vice versa.